# Sharepoint Designer Workflow with multiple tasks in sequence

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have a multi-step Sharepoint workflow in task list A that starts when a new task is created in that list and creates a task in another list, B. When that task in list B is completed, I would like the workflow in list A to create another task in list C.

I am using Sharepoint Designer 2007 to build all of this and at the moment I have this represented by multiple steps. So, step one is to create the task in the other list, and store its ID as a variable. Step 2 is conditional on a value in the task created by step one being marked complete, and it creates a task in the next list, and so on.

However, when I run the workflow, it marks its status as complete as soon as the item in the first list is completed, and does not go on to create the task outlined in Step 2 of the workflow.

I would like to know why the workflow is marking itself complete at the end of step one, and why the subsequent steps are not executed. Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I feel some problem with your logic.

You should have two workflows for doing this task

1. Workflow associated with list A to create a task in list B
2. Workflow associated with list B to create a task in list C

I shall explain it step by step.

1. You need to create a hidden field in List B to store list A's ID
2. Create a workflow associated with A on item creation for creating new item in B and copy the A's ID in B's hidden field
3. Create another workflow associated with list B for creating new item in C. You can get the A's record by comparing the A's id field with B's hidden field